# Как заставить вывести изображение?

Tags: java, swing

Пишу программу в которой рисованный объект должен двигаться из одного места в другое.
Расчёт координат проходит в цикле (без ошибок), я их для контроля вывожу на консоль.
В этом же цикле(после каждой итерации) я пытаюсь обновить нарисованное изображение на Label

```
mainLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(sr));
```

Но почему-то положение объекта меняется только после того, как весь цикл сдвигов объекта закончится.
Визуально объект просто перепрыгивает в новое место (без видимого перемещения)
У меня есть предположение, что картинку после каждой итерации цикла нужно принудительно вывести из буфера на экран.
Но как это сделать не знаю. Подскажите.
Если не в этом дело, подскажите в чём ошибка?
Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Анимацию нужно делать в отдельном потоке!

Comment: Мне не нужно анимацию делать в отдельном потоке. Я специально хочу, чтобы программа прервала другие действия и в течении какого-то времени выводила изображения на экран. Вопрос в том, почему программы обновляет изображение только после окончания цикла (или, может быть, после выхода из метода)?

Comment: Если это `swing`, то он устроен так, что сам принимает решение о перерисовке.

Comment: Да, конечно, это swing.

Comment: Как это  - сам принимает решение? А я не могу принять решение и перерисовать? Странная постановка ответа!

Comment: Вот хорошая статья о том как тригерятся события по перерисовке, даже есть сцылко на примеры. https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/painting.html#triggers